# carry-less multiplication optimization for ECC over GF(2^m) in MIRACL

Tags: c, cryptography, compiler-optimization, elliptic-curve, galois-field

[Link](https://github.com/certivox/miracl) to MIRACL crypto library by CertiVox

Following the instructions in [fastgf2m.txt](https://github.com/CertiVox/MIRACL/blob/master/fastgf2m.txt), I've been able to get everything to compile. However, after execution, the benchmark (bmark.exe) program halts when evaluating curves over GF(2^m) with error, "This is not a point on the curve!"

I am able to get everything to work without the optimization but I'm unsure where the problem exists. I haven't modified any curve parameters and followed instructions in the distribution. I'm compiling on 64-bit Windows 8.1, on an Intel i7-3520M.

If anyone has any advice on how to correct this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method outlined in `fastgf2m.txt` is for generating unrolled code associated with a fixed m value determined at compile time. The `bmark` program changes `m` at runtime, and so the unrolled code will often not be correct in this case. The documentation could be clearer on this point.

Also make sure your processor does support the `PCLMULQDQ` instruction - many older processors will not.

It might be better to test the method on the `ecsgen2`/`ecssign2`/`ecsver2` programs to implement `ECDSA` over `GF(2^283)` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I believe I have correctly set the word length of the optimizations. I'm trying to get it to work over GF(2^233) so I've used `#define MR_COMBA2 4` which I believe should be good for values of m up to 256 bits. It will run the GF(2^163) curves but without problem and crash on GF(2^233).  However, I will begin testing on the programs you've suggested.